Do the three bars connecting these notes mean something other than 1/32nd of a beat?
In the opening of Strauss’ Also Sprach Zarathustra, the bass notes look like 32nd notes, albeit with a minim style head. What does the notation mean? What does the similar notation ‘disconnected’ between the crotchet notes mean?


It's tremolo notation.  Others have offered literal notation of the result.   While one or two slashes are played as a 'measured tremolo' with specific note lengths, three slashes generally indicate an 'unmeasured tremolo' - just fit in as many notes as are practical.  So if you wish a three-slash tremolo to be played literally as 32nd notes it's a good idea to write out the first group in full.
Gould p.224.


This is a good answer; to fend off the follow-up question it might be nice to address the rhythmic notation, as beginners might be confused by the combination of beams and hollow note heads or by the two "side by side" quarter notes taking up only one beat.

The use of 'non trem' seems odd. It sounds like someone's mind was changed.

I don't think I have seen the words "non trem", or I just don't remember whether I have seen it. But I have seen the opposite, the term "tremolo" in order to indicate that it is supposed to be unmeasured. Tremolo being unmeasured is normal use of the word "tremolo" among bowed string players.

Those lines certainly don't mean 1/32 notes! They refer to tremolo, where the notes on either side of them are played quickly and alternately, rather like a drum roll. The note values stand as is, to make the bars have the right note lengths in total.

Sort of.  Though three slashes conventionally mean an unmeasured tremolo, they still might mean a 1/32 tremolo.   And three slashes certainly mean a 1/16 one, two slashes an 1/8.

The disconnected and connected beams both indicate an unmeasured tremolo, as explained elsewhere. The reason for the difference in the beams is that, while the open note heads with stems (i.e. half notes) clearly convey two beats of tremolo, connecting the two quarter notes (one beat of tremolo) would make them look like 32nd notes, rather than a tremolo.
